# Jqgrid - grouping feature with subgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Subgrid feature is automatically disabled when the grouping is turned on. Is there a way we can implement subgrid feature if the grouping is turned on? Any idea if the latest release of jqgrid support both these features? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping feature with subgrid is now available with Jqgrid 4.3 release. Please check [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/grouping-with-subgrid-feature/). I have downloaded 4.4.1 and working fine...